# How to diagnose my computer's issue?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, cpu, freeze, hardware-failure

I have a serious problem here, my desktop suddenly shutdown. I was testing my HDD and I found that it has some bad sectors, so I bought a new one: WD GREEN 500gb. After that everything went right, however this two days, while working or playing games on my desktop, it turns off on it’s own. I even installed other operating systems, and while installing lubuntu 15 it shutdown during the installation. I'm sure there is something wrong with the hardware but I don't know what piece is damaged.

What steps can I use to diagnose the problem?

Comment: It could be overheating, and going into thermal shutdown.  If you can install a program that graphs the tempurate of your cpu like speedfan or whatever your motherboard manufacturer provides.  See if it is overheating.

Comment: A bad Power supply (PSU) could also cause this.

Comment: I'd suggest you reseat all the connections inside your PC rig and make sure there are no loose cables! It might also be a good idea to [test the power supply unit](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-a-Power-Supply) just as @curtis mentioned. If it's faulty, you should most definitely replace it ASAP. If that piece of hardware is corrupted, it could cause even more damage to your system. Good luck!

Comment: @cybernard I tried it. The temp was between 47-50 Celcius which is not that much in a Core 2 Duo processor

Comment: Did you check the windows event viewer for critical and error entries.  It has 2 important areas **system** and **application**.  You may also want to look for bugfix errors.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test the HW is run **Windows Live CD (Windows PE)** running from CD/DVD/USB.
First of all I advise to create a bootable CD/USB to boot from with test utilities. Run **Memtest86+** from DOS mode to test RAM. After that Boot to Windows PE and start working, run test utilities to load CPU/RAM and hence, to consume more power. You can use AIDA64 with burn-in tests inside. If it doesn't crash, it's likely not motherboard/RAM/video related.

If it turns off in Win PE mode - take a note if it first falls to BSOD or immediately turn off. Note that you need enable blue screen debug (BSOD) in Windows (if it is turned off) so that you can read BSOD dump files later with [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html). If it just turns off immediately, it is very likely caused by PSU.

P>S> Good Windows PE builds by [Strelec](http://sergeistrelec.ru/winpe_10/56-winpe80-x86-native-x86-winpe10-sergei-strelec-x64-20160607-english-version.html)
Or you can use [AOMEI PE Builder](http://www.aomeitech.com/pe-builder.html) to build your own PE.